# Associativity of Operation * on Path-homotopy Classes Proof (Supposedly Trivial Question)

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Munkres' Topology Book where the Proof of Associativity of  Operation * on Path-homotopy Classes, there is a statement which I don't quite understand.

Background Info:
Munkres defines a path $k_{a,b}$ in X as follows: On $[0,a]$ it is equal to the positive linear map of $[0,a]$ to $I=[0,1]$ followed by $f$; on $[a,b]$ it equals the positive linear map of $[a,b]$ to $I$ followed by $g$; and on $[b,1]$ it equals the positive linear map of $[b,1]$ to $I$ followed by $h$.

He then defines $p:I\to I$ which is a map when restricted to $[0,a]$, $[a,b]$ and $[b,1]$ equals the positive linear maps of those intervals onto $[0,c]$, $[c,d]$, and $[d,1]$ respectively.

It is then claimed that $k_{c,d}\circ p=k_{a,b}$. Why?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Most topology texts insist that a path in $X$ has to be a map $[0,1] \to X$. However the classic  book on Knot Theory by Crowell and Fox defines a path in $X$ to be a pair $(f,r)$ where $r \geqslant 0$ and $f: [0, \infty ) \to X$ is a map constant on $[r,\infty)$. With an easily defined composition the paths in $X$ form a category, in particular associativity holds. There is a variation on this method in my book "Topology and Groupoids". These approached make it easier for students and seem more understandable.

Comment: You have to check that $k_{c,d} (p(t)) = k_{a,b}(t)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. Break your proof into three cases: $t \in [0,a]$; $t \in [a,b]$, $t \in [b,1]$. In each case, use the given formulas, or if the formula is given in words like "the positive linear map of $[0,a]$ to $[0,1]$" then first convert that into a mathematical formula. Is that enough to get you going?

Comment: Yes, I get it now, thanks!